# ASP.NET Core Web API FromHeader binding x-api-key header

Tags: asp.net-core, http-headers, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a `x-api-key` header that I want to bind to my controller paramter. I tried the below code but the parameter is still null.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Get([FromHeader] xApiKey) {
    var apikey = xApiKey;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After 5 minutes of posting this question I found the answer [here](https://codingblog.carterdan.net/2019/10/08/aspnetcore-json-api-cheat-sheet/). So using the `name` property of FromHeader.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Get([FromHeader(Name = "x-api-key")] apiKey) {
     // code here
}
```